# Why is Spring not running my Validator?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and I am making a Validator but it looks like Spring is never running it.

Here is my Validator is a easy one right now just checking for two fields

```
public class MemberRequestValidator  implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class aClass) {
        return MemberRequest.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        MemberRequest mr = (MemberRequest) obj;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "content", "Content field is Required");

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "areacode", "Area code field is Required");


    }

}
```

Now my controller looks like the following:

```
 @InitBinder("memberrequest")
    public void initMemberRequestBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new MemberRequestValidator());
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveRequest(@ModelAttribute @Valid MemberRequest mr,  BindingResult result)
    {

        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            LOGGER.debug("Pages had errors on it... returning to input page");
                return new ModelAndView("question");
        }
        else
        {
                String Ticket = mService.sentWebRequest(mr);

                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Ticket t = new Ticket();
                t.setTicketDetails(Ticket);

                model.put("ticket", t);

                return new ModelAndView("thanks", model);
        }


    }
```

and in my JSP page I have the following:

```
 <c:url var="saveUrl" value="/mrequest/save.html" />

            <form:form modelAttribute="memberrequest"  action="${saveUrl}" name="memberrequest" id="memberrequest">
```

so if I dont enter any data in on the form I should hit the errors but I dont?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `@ModelAttribute("memberrequest")` in handler or modelAttribute="memberRequest" in form and `@initBinder("memberRequest")`